# Error with Oauth in Facebook JS SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-oauth

I am encountering a weird issue when trying to do an advanced login flow using the Facebook API with long-lived tokens stored on my server (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#long-via-code)

The issue is this: Upon shipping a generated code back to my client (a JS web app in this case) I should be calling the graph API to generate a long-lived token. My call looks something like this:

```
var requestUri = "/oauth/access_token?code=" + code + "&client_id=" + facebookAppId + "&redirect_uri=" + redirectUrl;
FB.api(requestUri, function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

However, upon callback of this FB.api request, I get a response that looks like the following:

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "unknown error",
        "type": "http"
    }
}
```

There is also a JS error in the console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

What is really strange about all of this is that if I look at the raw response of the call to /oauth/access_token I see the expected response with a 200 success code

```
{
    "access_token": "...",
    "machine_id": "...",
    "expires_in": 5184000
}
```

I can determine from this that the JSON response isn't be read correctly by my browser (Chrome in this case). In fact if I paste the raw response above into Chrome Dev JS Console, it gives me the same JS error. However, if I were to assign it to a variable in the console, there are no problems. It basically seems as though something is going wrong in Facebook's JS SDK and the response object never is properly returned to the callback function. Has anyone encountered anything like this before? I can't seem to find an answer for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did find a workaround for this for the time being. I'm pretty sure the problem stems from somewhere in the Facebook JS SDK. To get around this, I made a raw call using AJAX to the graph API, in this case using AngularJS

```
$http.get("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token....)
```

This way, I can get the response I need without having to deal with an error that I can't get to.

I can also get away with not using FB.api because I am requesting an access token and don't need to worry about the JS SDK managing it for me.

If anyone has any other solutions to the initial problem, I would be delighted to hear them. I still would like to use Facebook SDK wherever possible.